# Triggering a click event based on browser # link

Tags: jquery

I currently have a gallery of thumbnails which when clicked animates a modal window and loads in content via ajax. I have used 'window.location.hash' to create a unique url for the content that is loaded into my modal.

```
var base_url = "http://www.ddbremedy.co.uk/siteupdate/";

$('#work_gallery li a').on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    postLink = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location.hash = postLink.replace(base_url, "");
});
```

The modal then animates in and the content loads via ajax. Then when I close the modal I add this code to remove the hash and url suffix that was added when the ajax page was loaded.

```
if ("pushState" in history) {
    history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
} else {
    window.location.hash = "";
}
```

This all works fine, but what I need is to be able to take the ajax link that was generated and when pasted into a new window, automatically trigger a click event on the correct thumbnail to load the correct content. I know can basically detect if there is a hash and particular word in the url like this:

```
var pathname = window.location.hash;
if (pathname.indexOf("work") >= 0) {
    // trigger click event on correct thumbnail to launch modal   
}
```

I know i need to probably trigger a click event like this:

```
$('#work_gallery li a').trigger('click');
```

but I can't figure out how to apply it to the correct thumbnail based on the url of the ajax content.  The modal itself is done using jquery, without any plug-ins and I also need to keep it that way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you not use: `$('#work_gallery li a[href="'+pathname+'"').trigger('click')`?

Comment: I am confused a little. Is there only one gallery thumbnail? If not, I think you better use IDs of that thumbnails. on click change domain to my.domain.com/gallery/'galleryIDnumber' and on every gallery/somenumber page get the number part of that url and trigger a click event to that element whose ID is in the url.

Comment: Hi Hasan, no there are about 20 links within the container

Comment: BenM, it didn't work, but I get the feeling you may be on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working. @BenM pointed me in the right dirrection. This is how I did it:

First I run a function called 'checkUrl' which checks the URL to see if it contains a hash.

```
checkUrl = function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {

    }
};

checkUrl();
```

Then within the if statement I store the hash path into variable and split it from the hash. I then store the string after the hash into a variable.

```
var pathname = window.location.hash,
    rez = pathname.split('#'),
    linkUrl = rez[1];
```

I then pass that variable as a selector for the link that has that particular href and trigger a click event on the corresponding link, which then animates and loads in the correct modal.

```
$("a[href='http://www.ddbremedy.co.uk/siteupdate/" + linkUrl + "']").trigger('click');
```

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.